# "pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)" error while trying to install R

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I use Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.

The problem started after I added R repository using the below command from [these instructions](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-install-r-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus/).

```
 sudo echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Below is the error I'm now getting when I run `sudo apt-get update`

```
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_ubuntu_xenial_InRelease - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
E: Failed to stat /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/cran.rstudio.com_bin_linux_ubuntu_xenial_Packages - pkgAcqTransactionItem::TransactionState-stat (2: No such file or directory)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Release
```

---

This problem was solved by the solution provided in the response to it.

Although the R install went fine, I could not update due to the error. Hence I had to remove the other CRAN entries in the `sources.list` and substitute it with the one recommended to me in the response to my query. This resolved the issue. I used nano to edit the file as it did not throw any warning messages while doing the edit.

Comment: This snippet is a mere fragment of the truth, and does NOT show what you did (which mistakes you made) to get to this state. We care not which "directions" you "followed". We can help if you show us the actual commands you executed, and their results.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

1. remove duplicate entries from */etc/apt/sources.list* - it should contain only one about R as follows:

   ```
   deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
   ```
2. remove old apt package lists with `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists`
3. update package lists with `sudo apt-get update`
4. resume installation session with `sudo apt-get install -f`

You can consult official [Cran page](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/) for correct R installation details for Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi N0rbert - Thanks for a quick response. My installation did go well without any issue. You mean both the lines with CRAN to be removed as folows ..# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
# deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/

Comment: See my updated answer above.

Comment: ok let me try again. only thing that it pushed me to backout was the flood of messages when I tried editing the sources.list file . let me do it again and get back

Comment: Thanks so much N0rbert. You saved my  another day as I could get past the apt-get update . It worked as you said . However since R is already installed , do I still need to install again ( as said in step4) ? So far its working OK. I did till step 3 as per your response. Do I need to reinstall R as per step 4 again :)

Comment: You do not need to reinstall if apt-get is OK (run `sudo apt-get check` to be sure). `R` should work as before.

Comment: This is what ap-get check gives .... Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done   ( am hoping its all fine then , R is also working ok ). Thanks so much to you again.

Comment: Seems to be OK.